# Conditionally append a query string to an angular href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building some links in AngularJS v1.2.16 like such:

```
<a ng-href="/foo/{{id}}/t/{{list[m].id}}/{{id2}}/{{otherId}}">Click here!</a>
```

That works great.

Now I have a query parameter `query` I'd like to append to the end if it exists.

I tried to do it like so:

```
<a ng-href="/foo/{{id}}/{{otherId}}{{ query ? '?q=' + query : "" }}">Click here!</a>
```

I end up with the following, because angular just renders the entire contents to the tag into the link like so:

```
<a href="/foo/2/4%7B%7B%7B%20query%20?%20%27?q=%27%20+%query%20:">Click here!</a>
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, your attempt didn't work because you have used double-quotes `""` inside other double-quotes. Change the `<a>` to the following and it will work:

```
<a ng-href="/foo/{{id}}/{{otherId}}{{ query ? '?q=' + query : '' }}">Click here!</a>
```

But, I agree with the other answers - sometimes it's better and cleaner to generate a value (in this case, URL) in the controller, especially if you want to build a unit-test around this value.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to make a model for the url in the controller than making it like that, it will also avoid many $watch binding so better performance and cleaner

```
<a ng-href="{{myUrl}}">Click here!</a>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.myUrl = 'foo/'+id+'/.../'+(qry ? ...)+'...';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the URL construction in the Controller.

### HTML

```
<a ng-href="getQueryUrl()">Click here!</a>
```

### Controller.js

```
$scope.getQueryUrl = function getQueryUrlFn(){
   return "/foo/bar?query=abc";
}
```

Comment: FWIW: I think my answer has a declarative & semantic advantage over @Sn0opr's: By indicating that it's a function in your `ng-href`, you're declaring "this is not some static variable".  Using a `$scope` variable hides that semantic difference.  As for the `$watch` performance, it's unlikely that a URL would change with such frequency to impact `$watch` significantly.

Comment: But this doesn't actually work. `ng-href` only supports templates while this uses an expression. If you do this the href will literally be "getQueryUrl()" as opposed to some value that the function would've returned had it been called.